# Drawing LWJGL Slick Fonts ontop of 2d scene

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

so i need to draw these fonts on top of my 2D scene's sprites, but whatever i try they end up behind the sprites, how do i get around this? how can i print the text on top of my sprites?

here is my font loading method:

```
Font awtFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15);
font        = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, antiAlias);
//here i draw other textures
 //and here i draw the string
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);
glPushMatrix();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, SpritesLoaded);
org.newdawn.slick.Color.black.bind();
font.drawString(px, py, gtxt, mycol);
glPopMatrix();
glPopAttrib();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you drawing it over 3d scene? If so try using that code after you draw your 2d sprites. If its just 2d sprites, try using that code without the push and pop matrices, and try using it after you draw sprites.